# Dealing with lots (and lots) of JButtons Elegantly

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jscrollpane

Just wondering what would be the best way to go about including tons of Buttons in a Swing application without 
affecting performance too much?

At the moment I have a few ideas:

1. [Brute Force] Display a list of JButtons all using the same action listener.

   -this method is essentially brute force and causes obvious problems
2. [Dynamic Visiblity] Hide/Display//Remove/Add JButtons based on the scroller position so that a limited amount are active at any time.

   -I haven't tried (or any of the below) this but it seems like it would get quite messy*
3. [Fake Buttons] Create a Large JPanel with a mouse Listener, Draw Rectangles to Panel when clicked based on mouse coordinates from a mouseListener.
4. [Dynamic Fake Buttons] Like number 3 except using a Small JPanel that only fills the window area. This is repainted every time the user scrolls (on a fake ScrollPane)

Any ideas on how best to deal with this problem?

Comment: Fake Buttons 2: use a JTable to hold your buttons. This also begs the question of why: why the need for many JButtons as this might affect the approach to your solution.

Comment: The elegant solution necessarily depends on the user's view of all the buttons, or alternately what it is the application is attempting to communicate about with the user through buttons.  Use lots of drop-downs; have one button generate a list of other buttons, have hierarchies of buttons, don't use buttons, use checkboxes or radio buttons or something that isn't standard -- all possibly good, no way to evaluate until we (or at least you) know what you want to do.

Comment: How many are 'tons of buttons'? Have you checked that they really affect the performance?